# What is the added value of using a 2-part model over an OLS model on a subsample when estimating health care expenditures?

Tags: regression, probability, logistic

I want to estimate the impact of having health insurance on health care expenditures and have a hunch that it is best to use a two-part model to first estimate the probability of using any health care and then estimating the amount spent by those who used health care. However, I am not clear on the advantage of using a two-part model over just running ordinary least squares regression on the subsample of people who used any health care. Any insight into the advantages of the 2-part model over OLS on the subsample of users, and the differences in these two approaches would be much appreciated!

Comment: What would you like to do with your model?  It will be very difficult to estimate the causal-effect of having health insurance on healthcare expenditures, but it could be interesting to describe simple differences and conditional associations.  Like @Mermex I am getting the sense that you are wondering about the Heckman correction, you might try it but I don't see it as a panacea, see my comment on Mermex's answer.  For better answers, describe the data, especially how health insurance and expenditures are measured.

Comment: For background literature, in case you aren't aware: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAND_Health_Insurance_Experiment

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable input M. Yes, selection bias is likely, especially given that the scheme is voluntary and the data are cross-sectional. I actually used propensity score matching in the analysis and made the assumption that the most important determinants of enrollment were observed through the questionnaire. However, I also want to show the results using OLS (and compare the insured and uninsured). What is the advantage of using OLS on a subsample of those who have had care vs. using a two-part model on the full dataset to look at expenditures conditional on health care use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sara, to understand the difference in the two models is to ask you what question you are trying to find an answer to:

1. What is the health care expenditure of those who have it?
2. What is the impact on having health insurance on health care expenditure?

To answer the first question, you have a subsample (as you refer to it) of those who have health insurance and there is observed health care expenditures as well as other explanatory variables (age, occupation, etc.). In this case, you are trying to explain variation in health care expenditures of people who choose to have health insurance. There is no way two answer your fist question.

The second question is more general. You need to have two groups of people with and without insurance. Also, if you just use OLS here on the subsample of insured people, you will get biased and inconsistent OLS parameter estimates due to self-selection bias, and you would not be able to correctly estimate the impact of having the insurance on the expenditure. So, Heckman's!

I hope that helps.

M

Comment: Dear Mermex, Thank you so much for your reply. I'm sorry if I didn't explain the subsample very well. I foresee two ways of estimating the impacts of health insurance on health expenditure. The first is to take a subsample of individuals who have any health care visits and compare their expenditures, controlling for health insurance status and other variables. The second is the two-part model (either log-transformed OLS or Heckman's sample selection model) to compare expenditures between the insured and uninsured. In my understanding, if I take a subsample of individuals with any expenditure..

Comment: and then compare expenditures between insured and uninsured (after controlling for other vars) I am effectively answering your question #1 above (what is the health care expenditure of those who have it). However, if I want to answer your question #2 above I need to use a two step model that takes into consideration the selection into insurance. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Sarah,

I was a little puzzled to think about whether there is a selection bias here. It seems that health insurance is bundled with other job benefits, and there is no self selection. However, those people who do not have health insurance are very different from those who do.

If there is a selection bias, OLS is biased and inconsistent. Selection bias is interpreted as a problem of omitted variables which can be corrected with the inverse mills ratio in your OLS.

The Heckman's procedure gets unbiased OLS parameter estimates. Testing their significance requires additional work, since the estimates of the covariance matrix of the parameter estimates are inconsistent - use bootstrapping to derive the appropriate asymptotic standard errors and test statistics.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heckman_correction.

M

Comment: I agree that there are big differences between those who have health insurance and those who do not.  Why do you say there is no self selection?  Also, I would be careful not to oversell the Heckman correction... unbiased parameter estimates still require some fairly strong assumptions http://smr.sagepub.com/content/18/4/395.short and http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-6419.00104/abstract

Comment: @Michael Bishop: My thinking was that you are not really self selected to have health insurance, i.e., it comes with a job. Unlike, you do choose to go to a college, where there is obvious self selection. Thanks for the links.

Comment: In this case I am talking about a developing country and a voluntary health insurance scheme so there is definitely self-selection into the scheme. Sorry for not making this clearer the first time. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are assuming something like this. People use health care if they are sick. If they use health care, than they spend more money on it. But, sick people will see more value on insurance and will be more likey to be insured. So, you will find out that insured people spends more money on health care, but this may be so due to selection bias.

And you seem to think that, if you use only the subsample of people who used health care, than you don't have this problem. However, think of this example. Assume you have a woman who wants to be pregnant and a man who doesn't want to have a child, both on their 30's. The woman than gets insured, but the man not. Both get sick and use health care, so they both are in your subsample. However, they have different probabilities of being insured and they will spend different amount of money if she is pregnant. Thus selection bias will occur anyway.

So, what I'm saying is that restricting your subsample will not solve the selection bias problem. You still have to account for the different probabilities of people getting insurance.

Comment: Thank you Manoel. This is helpful. I am willing to accept the fact that there may be selection bias and have noted this as a limitation. However, given this limitation I was wondering if there is an advantage to using a two-part model and what this advantage is. I guess I don't really understand what the two-part model does that makes it more useful than just taking a subsample of individuals who used health care and comparing expenditures between insured and uninsured. But I think you have alluded to the difference - the 2-part model takes into account the prob of enrolment. Correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming that the two part model you refer is the Heckman correction sugested by Mermex, in this case, yeah, it will take into account the prob of enrolment. If it's not, than I don't know if it's ok to just estimate the probability of using health and then use this probability as a independent variable in the main regression. The heckman correction has this idea, but I think it's slightly different and has some assumptions to work.